# Android NullPointerException onClick

Tags: java, android, exception

I get a null pointer exception when I call flash(),more precisely I open the application (which works correctly, no force close) , then i hit menu button and select settings (start ActivitySettings),and when I go back it gives me the null pointer exception.

P.S. (I know the problem is flash() because I read it in logcat)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean isFlashOn = false;
    private Camera camera;
    public ImageButton imagebutton;
    String r,t;
    String scelta="btn0";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        t=CheckPrefsThm();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        ChooseThm();
        r = CheckPrefsImg();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Decision();
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View w) {

                flash();

            }
        });
    }

    public void flash() {
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        if(isFlashOn) {
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            isFlashOn = false;
            if(scelta.equals("btn1")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.powerg);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn0")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.traoff);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn2")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pushg);
            }   
            if(scelta.equals("btn3")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playg1);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn4")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playg2);
            }
        }
        else {
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            isFlashOn = true;  
            if(scelta.equals("btn1")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.powerg);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn0")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.traon);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn2")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pushgon);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn3")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playg1);
            }
            if(scelta.equals("btn4")) {
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playg2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.preferences, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);     
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                UpdatePrefs(r ,t);
                startActivityForResult(startNewActivityOpen,0);                 
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public String CheckPrefsImg() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String result = prefs.getString("img","uno");

        return result;
    }

    public String CheckPrefsThm() { 
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String result = prefs.getString("thm","dark");

        return result;
    }

    public void UpdatePrefs(String img,String thm) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("img",img);
        editor.putString("thm",thm);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void ChooseThm() {
        if(t.equals("radiolight")) {
            this.setTheme(R.style.Light);
        }
        else{
            if(t.equals("radiodark")) {
                this.setTheme(R.style.Dark);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Decision() {
        if(r.equals("uno") ) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imagebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.torcia);
            scelta="btn0";
        }
        else if(r.equals("due")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            imagebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            scelta="btn1";
        }
        else if(r.equals("tre")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
            imagebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            scelta="btn2";
        }
        else if(r.equals("quattro")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
            imagebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
            scelta="btn3";
        }
        else if(r.equals("cinque")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);
            imagebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
            scelta="btn4";
        }
    }  
}
```

edit: here is my logcat

```
03-16 13:47:21.174: D/dalvikvm(29612): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-16 13:47:21.204: E/jdwp(29612): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-16 13:47:21.204: D/dalvikvm(29612): Debugger has detached; object registry had   1 entries
03-16 13:47:21.404: D/dalvikvm(29612): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 6% free 12166K/     12931K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
03-16 13:47:21.404: I/dalvikvm-heap(29612): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.899MB for   484456-byte allocation
03-16 13:47:21.449: D/dalvikvm(29612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 7% free 12638K/      13447K, paused 19ms+1ms, total 45ms
03-16 13:47:22.429: D/libEGL(29612): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-16 13:47:22.434: D/libEGL(29612): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-16 13:47:22.439: D/libEGL(29612): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-16 13:47:22.444: D/(29612): Device driver API match
03-16 13:47:22.444: D/(29612): Device driver API version: 10
03-16 13:47:22.444: D/(29612): User space API version: 10 
03-16 13:47:22.444: D/(29612): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct  16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
03-16 13:47:22.579: D/OpenGLRenderer(29612): Enabling debug mode 0
03-16 13:47:29.734: W/Camera(29612): Camera server died!
03-16 13:47:44.749: D/AbsListView(29612): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-16 13:47:45.444: D/dalvikvm(29612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 108K, 6% free 12965K/    13703K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 25ms
03-16 13:47:45.474: E/SensorManager(29612): thread start
03-16 13:47:45.474: D/SensorManager(29612): registerListener::handle=0name=LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000Listener=android.view.
OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41e66718
03-16 13:47:45.554: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29612): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE       spans cannot have a zero length
03-16 13:47:45.554: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29612): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE       spans cannot have a zero length
03-16 13:47:51.909: D/SensorManager(29612): unregisterListener::  Listener=android.view.OrientationEventListener

$SensorEventListenerImpl@41e66718
03-16 13:47:51.909: D/Sensors(29612): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay     200ms
03-16 13:47:51.909: I/Sensors(29612): sendDelay --- 200000000
03-16 13:47:51.909: D/SensorManager(29612): JNI - sendDelay
03-16 13:47:51.909: I/SensorManager(29612): Set normal delay = true
03-16 13:47:53.319: W/Camera(29612): Camera server died!
03-16 13:47:53.329: I/Choreographer(29612): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-16 13:47:53.409: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29612): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-16 13:47:53.409: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29612): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-16 13:48:01.899: D/AndroidRuntime(29612): Shutting down VM
03-16 13:48:01.899: W/dalvikvm(29612): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411542a0)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at com.burattiluca.latorcia.MainActivity.flash(MainActivity.java:47)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at com.burattiluca.latorcia.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-16 13:48:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(29612):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line in `flash()` is `MainActivity.java:47`? That's your problem.

Comment: Do you override onActivityResult method?

Comment: i've added logcat, but i don't use onActivityResult..maybe that's the problem

Comment: Then why call startActivityForResult(startNewActivityOpen,0);  Just call startActivity(startNewActivityOpen); to see if it helps.

Comment: @HoanNguyen okay now i use startActivity(startNewActivityOpen) but the problem persists, i'm going crazy! but thanks for the help!
(however i found this problem after updated the sdk to the last version, before the update i had no problem)

Comment: I think you should move onClickListener in onStart to onCreate.

Comment: @HoanNguyen ok i did it but didn't resolve the problem; btw i noticed that the problem appears only if i return to main activity to much fast, on the contrary if i'm moving between these activities slowly i'm not having problems. ( more precisely when in logcat appears "camera server died" work everything prefect )

Comment: I guess the only thing you can do is to check if (camera != null) in the flash method.

Comment: @HoanNguyen if camera == null what can i do to avoid the problem?     thanks

Comment: Did you call flash() anywhere else beside onClickListener()? If not then somehow if you return to Main activity fast, the touch event (which is when you touch the menu item to start Setting) is being sent to an image. Is the Setting item over the image when the menu pop up?

Comment: @HoanNguyen yes it is

Answer (score 0):

you have not used setcontentview() in your onCreate()...i guess that is generating nullpointerexception...put your logcat output for more information

Comment: i used setcontentview(), is inside decide() method and in fact when i open the app i have no problem, i get nullpointer when i return to this activity from settingsactity

Answer (score 0):

I think camera is having null because `Camera.open()` return null If the device does not have a back-facing camera.

Read android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29).

Test this on device and put this code try catch block and make sure you have added all permission which is required for access the camera above application tag.

Comment: i'm testing on a galaxy s3

Comment: Debug the app and i guess you will get null in camera.

Comment: i have put the onclicklistener with flash() method between /* */ but the app is still very slow and when i go back to main activity i get fc...so i think the problem is not flash(), however i posted logcat.

Comment: @user2177749 Check in your at line MainActivity.java:47. Its caused NPE.

Comment: yes you are right and logcat found the error at camera.getParameters().. btw it's strange, it happens only when i go back to this activity from the other (SettingsActivity) , i think this could be important. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to the following code to see if it work

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// remove onClickListener    
imagebutton.setOnClickListener(null);
Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);     
switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_settings:
            UpdatePrefs(r ,t);
            startActivityForResult(startNewActivityOpen,0);                 
            return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Then **onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View w){

    flash();

    }
});
}
```

Comment: i tried but doesn't work, i'm pretty sure that the problem is camera.release() which takes too much to release the camera, i think i will rebuild the project from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are releasing camera within **onStop()** and once you come back to activity and click imageButton which makes a call to flash() method. So , within flash() method it is using camera which would be null since you released it in inStop() while switching to next Activity.

As a solution to this you have to reinitialize the camera in onResume() of your Activity.